# Create a tilt-shift filter like instagram in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, uiimageview, instagram

I trying to create a tilt-shift filter of the image like instagram or iDarkroom in iOS.

My proposed method is use different Gaussian Blur levels for the partial image. But I don't known how to control the area to apply different Gaussian Blur Levels, especially when User can change the effect area by rotate, scale, etc.

Sorry about my complex presentation but simply, I want to create a tilf-shift tool for iOS like in Instagram.

I search and found this powerful framework https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage, but it's not good solution if include this huge framework to my tiny apps

Comment: "it's not good solution if include this huge framework to my tiny apps" - physically, this framework adds only 1.5-2 MB to the on-disk size of any application using it, which isn't really any larger than other static libraries you might use. As far as impact on your application, it will take far more lines of code to write your own tilt-shift implementation than to just use the one in this framework. There are legitimate shortcomings of this framework, but code or executable size aren't really among them.

Comment: Also, I did see your feature request for an adjustable orientation on the tilt-shift filter, and I am working on that now. You've probably also seen the GPUImageToneCurveFilter, which might help with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079607/photoshop-like-curves-tool-in-objective-c).

Comment: @Brad: Thank you so much for your answer. I really need this function for my apps. Hope you have this function in GPUImage. Anw, GPUImage is the most powerful framework about image processing on iOS I ever seen. Thanks you for make it open source
<p>P/S: When I asked the previous question about curves, I hadn't known about GPUImage, so I created my own Curve filter for my issue, It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution:

Use filter **GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter** and change computing *distanceFromCenter* on this code:

```
distanceFromCenter = abs((textureCoordinate2.x - excludeCirclePoint.x) *
aspectRatio*cos(angle) + (textureCoordinate2.y-excludeCirclePoint.y)*sin(angle));
```

Comment: How do you get angle... There is no angle in GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter.m file

Comment: You can add it in your shader by yourself. `uniform highp float angle;`

Answer (score 0):

GPUImage framework worked perfectly for my question.
GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter for radial tiltshif as Oleg Kovtun's answer above
and GPUImageTiltShiftFilter for linear one.

Update answer for someone need

Comment: Is it possible make all filters like instagram by GPUImage?

Comment: @PramodTapaniya you might want to have a look at https://github.com/KimDaeWook/GPUImage-Instagram