# Gaussian selective linear blur shader like in Instagram

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a tilf-shift filter like instagram in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256100/create-a-tilf-shift-filter-like-instagram-in-objective-c)

I need to implement linear blur in my iOS app. And I want to rotate unblurred line by angle around excluded circle point.
I use https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage and it is a really great framework, but it doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: As you can see in the above-linked duplicate question, I'm working on adding the ability to control the angle of the tilt-shift effect. However, if you need this right now, you're more than welcome to modify what I have there to support this. The entire source code for everything in this filter is made available to you, so I've done 90% of the work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that similiar question. I'm trying to make this filter based on your **GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter** filter. And as I understand - I have to change _textureCoordinateToUse_ parameter in fragment shader. And also, I want to thank you for your cool framework! If I find a solution, I definitely will write it here.